# Vue works on Web serve after uninstalling vue

Tags: vue.js

I wanna know how and why .vue file is working after i uninstalling vue.
here is how i installed vue in the first place.

```
$ sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
+ @vue/cli@4.2.3 #
added 1113 packages from 648 contributors in 58.563s
```

below is where its installed 
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli

since i didnt wanna put vue in /local i decided to uninstall vue.
After i did `npm run serve` codes i wrote on vue working absolutely fine..
Does anyone know why so ?

Comment: your project has its own node_modules, vue cli is only tooling to help you its not needed to run your project

Comment: [Lawrence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone) Thank you for commenting! I figured why its running still. But is there any effect uninstalling vue cli? i just dont want to freak out when something i do not intend happens

Comment: Its probably compiled into a .js file.

Comment: `@vue/cli` is the tool to use help you developing with Vue. If you look closely in your `node_modules` you will see that you installed `vue` package in your project. That's what matters.